# SQL (oracle) - how to query multiple changed values from multiple tables

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to pull an audit of all the values that were changed in a specified time period from multiple tables. Is there a simpler way of writing the below?

```
select property_number, 'table1', count(*)
    from table1
   where start_date between to_date('07/01/2017','mm/dd/yyyy') and to_date('09/30/2017', 'mm/dd/yyyy')
group by property_number
union all
  select property_number, 'table2', count(*)
    from table2
   where start_date between to_date('07/01/2017', 'mm/dd/yyyy') and to_date('09/30/2017', 'mm/dd/yyyy')
group by property_number
union all
  select property_number, 'table3', count(*)
    from table3
   where start_date between to_date('07/01/2017', 'mm/dd/yyyy') and to_date('09/30/2017', 'mm/dd/yyyy')
group by property_number
union all
  select property_number, 'table4', count(*)
    from table4
   where start_date between to_date('07/01/2017', 'mm/dd/yyyy') and to_date('09/30/2017', 'mm/dd/yyyy')
group by property_number
union all
  select property_number, 'table5', count(*)
    from table5
   where start_date between to_date('07/01/2017', 'mm/dd/yyyy') and to_date('09/30/2017', 'mm/dd/yyyy')
group by property_number
```

Comment: Possibly not since data resides in multiple tables. Why are you not working with **one** table with an indicator field to distinguish? Similarly structured tables should never be separate objects in schema. Learn to normalize for efficiency, scalability, and query maintainability.

Comment: On a sidenote: If you want dates, don't use string literals and convert them to dates, but have date literals instead: `where start_date between date '2017-07-01' and date '2017-09-30'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider a CTE for a DRY-er solution.

```
WITH master_all AS
  (SELECT property_number, 'table1' AS "indicator"
   FROM table1
   UNION ALL 
   SELECT property_number, 'table2'
   FROM table2
   UNION ALL 
   SELECT property_number, 'table3'
   FROM table3
   UNION ALL 
   SELECT property_number, 'table4'
   FROM table4
   UNION ALL 
   SELECT property_number, 'table5'
   FROM table5)

SELECT property_number, indicator, Count(*) AS "Audit_Count"
FROM  master_all
WHERE start_date BETWEEN to_date('07/01/2017', 'mm/dd/yyyy') 
                     AND to_date('09/30/2017', 'mm/dd/yyyy')
GROUP BY property_number, indicator;
```

But once again, consider a schema adjustment and append all similar structured tables with indicator field into one master table.

Comment: Thanks! Had to take off the tickmarks off the 'Audit_count' and move the group by after the where clause, just fyi.

Comment: Whoops! Sorry about that. Fixed. And look into migrating the tables together...saves you a lot of pain down the road. Happy databse-ing.

Comment: Definitely will do. appreciate the help. Btw it should be 'table1' as indicator and count(*) as Audit_Count